# How to derive kinematics equations using calculus?

Tags: kinematics, differentiation, integration, mathematics, calculus

I read derivation of kinematics equations using calculus:

$$a=\frac{\text dv}{\text dt}$$
$$\implies \text dv=a\text dt$$
$$\implies \int_{v_0}^v\text dv=\int_0^t a\text dt$$
$$\implies v-v_0=at$$
$$\implies v=v_0+at\tag1$$

I know finding antiderivatives and basic concepts of integration:

I cannot understand:

1. How can we take $dt$ in the first equation to the other side when $dv/dt$ is not a fraction?
2. In third equation how have we placed the upper and lower limits in LHS of velocity and in RHS of time?
3. In third equation we have only $dv$ in LHS. Then what will be the function we are integrating?

Lastly can you please suggest some websites from where  I can learn how to integrate both sides of an equation like done above.

Please provide me the answers.

Comment: You should ask this rather in [math.se].  This is about basics of integration. It has nothing to do with physics

Comment: dv/dt is absolutely a fraction. It is the change in velocity divided by the change in time. Equation 2 comes from algebra.

Comment: This post currently has 3 migration votes. However this question seems to use physics language even if the underlying issue is math. I close it as _homework-like_ even if it isn't exactly homework partly to hinder migration.

Answer (score 2):

1. Since the RHS in your first expression is a total derivative, it is OK to move the differentials around in this way.
2. $v_0\equiv v(t=0)$ and $v\equiv v(t)$, i.e., the velocity limits of integration are just the velocities evaluated at the time limits of integration.  Note that the velocity integral is abusing notation a bit, since the integration variable also appears as a limit of integration.  A slightly better way to write this integral would be $$\int_{v_0}^vdv',$$
   introducing the "dummy variable" $v'$ to act as the integration variable.
3. The integrand on the LHS is 1 :)

Comment: Could we also write $\int_{u(t_i)}^{u({t_f})}du(t)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

1) By error approximation we can show that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is actually the ratio of *dy* and *dx*.

2)In the third equation acceleration ***a*** is constant, and the variables are velocity and time. SO we integrate with respect to their corresponding limits.

3) $dv = 1.dv$ . So the integrand is unity i.e, ***1***.

Answer (score 2):

1. $\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ is not a fraction, but it is the limit of $\dfrac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ which is a fraction. The trick here is to do the algebraic manipulations before taking the limit.
2. The LHS integral is over the variable $v$, while the RHS is over the variable $t$, so the integration interval endpoints must be expressed in terms of values for the corresponding variable.
3. The function is the constant function $1$ in this case: $dv = 1\cdot dv$.

The Wikipedia article on Infinitesimal has good information on the mathematical issues.