# Upper and lower limits of integration in the derivation of kinematic equations?

Tags: kinematics, calculus

I have already read part of this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477664/how-to-derive-kinematics-equations-using-calculus), but I need further clarification.

In the derivation of kinematic equations, the following two lines are present:

Acceleration is constant.

$\text dv=a\text dt$

$\implies\int_{v_0}^v\text dv=\int_0^t a\text dt$

How can we take the integral of both sides with different upper and lower limits?

*I feel it is relevant to physics as I have only ever seen this in a physics derivation.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V(t) = v$$
$$V(0) = v_{0}$$

They are the same bounds, in to different variables, dv and dt.

Instead imagine doing the same operation slightly differently.

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = a$$

$$\int_{0}^{t} (\frac{dv}{dt})dt = \int_{0}^{t} a dt$$

$$v(t) - v(0) = at$$

By definition $v(0)$ is $v_{0}$

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you change variables in an integral $t\to v(t)$ . The $v_0$ and $v$ are the starting and ending values of the velocity, while  the $0$ and $t$ are the starting an ending values of  the time.